# loop over a list and its sub-strings seperated by comma

Tags: python, list

Can someone help me with below. I have a list like below.

```
list = ['INDIA,CHINA,JAPAN','FRANCE,IRELAND,ENGLAND']
```

I am trying to convert above list into below.

```
newlist = ['INDIA','CHINA','JAPAN','FRANCE','IRELAND','ENGLAND']
```

I have tried `split()` which is not working.

```
newlist = list.split(',')
```

Thanks much for your help.

Comment: `list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(sublst.split(',') for sublst in lst))`

Comment: All are correct. Thanks a lot guys..

Answer (score 2):

You should use `split` with the strings in the list, not the list:

```
L = ['INDIA,CHINA,JAPAN', 'FRANCE,IRELAND,ENGLAND']
new_L = [x for s in L for x in s.split(',')]
print(new_L)
```

Output:

```
['INDIA', 'CHINA', 'JAPAN', 'FRANCE', 'IRELAND', 'ENGLAND']
```

Answer (score 2):

It is never a good idea to name your variables same as python keywords or builtin methods. Try naming it something different. For this problem you do not need any explicit for loops, there are suitable list methods to do this for you:

```
list_ = ['INDIA,CHINA,JAPAN','FRANCE,IRELAND,ENGLAND']
newlist = ','.join(list_).split(',')

#Output:
['INDIA', 'CHINA', 'JAPAN', 'FRANCE', 'IRELAND', 'ENGLAND']
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
list_ = ['INDIA,CHINA,JAPAN','FRANCE,IRELAND,ENGLAND']
newlist = []
for i in list_:
   newlist += i.split(',')
```

**Output** :

```
['INDIA', 'CHINA', 'JAPAN', 'FRANCE', 'IRELAND', 'ENGLAND']
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
list = ['INDIA,CHINA,JAPAN','FRANCE,IRELAND,ENGLAND']

result = []

for i in list : 
  s = i.split(",") 
  for j in s : 
      result.append(j)

print(result)
```

output :

```
['INDIA', 'CHINA', 'JAPAN', 'FRANCE', 'IRELAND', 'ENGLAND']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list = ['INDIA,CHINA,JAPAN','FRANCE,IRELAND,ENGLAND']
newlist = []
for item in list:
    newlist.extend(item.split(','))
print(newlist)
```

This will produce:

> ['INDIA', 'CHINA', 'JAPAN', 'FRANCE', 'IRELAND', 'ENGLAND']

Answer (score 0):

You can use a List Comprehension to achieve this easily

```
list = ['INDIA,CHINA,JAPAN','FRANCE,IRELAND,ENGLAND']
print([word for string in list for word in string.split(',')])
```

**Output**

```
['INDIA', 'CHINA', 'JAPAN', 'FRANCE', 'IRELAND', 'ENGLAND']
```